# Access modifiers nbot permitted when provided explicit implementation for interface member in imlementing class C#

Tags: c#, oop

```
interface honda {

    void meth();
    protected void meth2();
}

class crv : honda { 
    void honda.meth() { }  //public not allowed
    void honda.meth2() { } //protected not allowed
}
```

I gave interface `honda` that has 2 abstract methods: 
meth(); which is **public** 
meth2(); which is **protected**

Whay do I get an error when i say `public void honda.meth(){}` or `protected honda.meth2() { }` in the implementing class `crv`?
I mean i have one assumption: It is beacuse by doing this, we provide default implementation for the method, so It is like in the interface but It is not. This assumption wpuld justify the error when I say `public void honda.meth(){}` but it does not justify the error whjen I try to say `protected honda.meth2() { }` since the `meth2()` is **protected** in the interface.
Could you please help me?

Comment: And what happens if you make a `crv` variable and try to call `.meth2` on it? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation

Comment: Oh, I think I see It now. If that would be possible It would make no sense because the point of doing void honda.meth() { } or void honda.meth2() { } is so thay can be accessed through in interface variable that points to an object, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By declaring the methods in the implementing class as `honda.meth`, this is an [explicit interface implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation). Basically, it means that these methods can only be called on an object of type `honda`, not `crv` so the access modifiers on `crv` are never going to be used.

If you wanted to be able to call these methods on types of both `honda` and `crv`, simply drop the `honda.` prefix from the method name in the implementing class like so:

```
interface honda {

    void meth();
    void meth2();
}

class crv : honda { 
    public void meth() { } 
    public void meth2() { }
}
```

Note that you can't specify an access modifier in an interface (`public`, `protected` etc.) unless you are using the [default implementations in interfaces](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/default-implementations-in-interfaces/) C# feature.

If `meth2` had to be protected, change `honda` to be an abstract class and `meth2` to be an abstract method:

```
public abstract class honda {
    
   public abstract void meth();
   protected abstract void meth2();

}
```

Comment: Your answer is great, but there can not be _object_ honda , ther only can be reference variable honda which, in this case, will point to a crv object and like you said the ref. variable honda will only be able to call the meth and meth2.

Comment: So As I understand, the methods are not even private right, instead they are handled in some way in CLR not be accessible even to crv objects inside the crv class, right?

Comment: The only difference here is how the C# compiler is allowing those methods to be called - it'll enforce the LHS of the call expression to be something of type `honda` as opposed to a type of `honda` OR `crv`. Under-the-hood in the CLR, I suspect the MSIL being run would be the same without using an explicit interface implementation since these are just public methods on a type.